# How to Change the Page headers made by Winui 3 Template Studio

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I don't know how to mention my problem. I have to show you in image:
[image]

As you can see, I want to change that. I know I have to change the text in Resources. But I want to change font family, Flow direction etc. On some Pages, I Don't want to show it AT ALL.

No codes required for this question. I don't have any!
Just make a project with some pages in "Template Studio for WinUI 3". You will see the code. I'm looking for it for a long time. please answer if you know where should I look for it or what should I do.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I want to change font family, Flow direction etc.**

You could try to change the value in the resources file to alter what is displayed in the NavigationView.

**On some Pages, I Don't want to show it AT ALL.**

The navigation pane projects add a Behavior to the NavigationView that allows different pages to customize or hide the Header when that page is shown.

`HeaderMode`: allows you to choose when to display the Header on that page (Always, Minimal,Never), Always is the default value.

If you want to hide the Header in some pages, you could set `HeaderMode="Never"`.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[NavigationViewHeaderBehavior](https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/blob/main/docs/UWP/projectTypes/navigationpane.md#navigationviewheaderbehavior)

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer but I'm new to WinUI. I found header Model Behavior but I can't find where the template is. the default template that uses that Behavior. can you please explain a little more and step by step maybe?

Comment: Ok I get it, I can now hide the Navigation header in page. I don't know If I'm doing it right. please tell me if I'm wrong. I Use this code in the Page constructor : `NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.SetHeaderMode(this, NavigationViewHeaderMode.Never);` Is it right or should I place it in ViewModel of the page. and I don't know how to change the template. I'm working on it.

Comment: Thanks, I read the link you posted and figure it out. I comment this for others that are new to winui 3 like me to understand easier. the default template is located at the bottom of the ShellPage.xaml file and for the header mode (hide it) you can read my last comment before this.